# useParam outside react component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to pass a variable value which uses useParam hook so i can pass it to my api which set outside of the component function.

VesselComponent.js :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchComponents } from "../../../features/componentsSlice";
import TreeItem from "@mui/lab/TreeItem";
import TreeView from "@mui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight";
import { Link, Outlet, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
export const api = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      // here
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/maintenance/${vesselId}`
    );
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
function VesselComponents() {
  // this line
  const vesselId = useParams();
  const { components, error, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.components
  );
// rest of the code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to pass a param to `api` that would help you have `vesselId` from other places including `useParams`

```
export const api = async (vesselId) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      // here
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/maintenance/${vesselId}`
    );
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Here is how we call it

```
const vesselId = useParams();
api(vesselId);
```

Comment: Thank you, this make sense as it gives me the ability to reuse it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use react hooks at the top level inside a component. You shouldn't call `useParams` in your `api` function. Instead, you should pass it to your `api` function and use some state to store the response from your API. Something like this:

```
export const api = async (vesselId) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      // here
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/maintenance/${vesselId}`
    );
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

function VesselComponents() {
  // this line
  const vesselId = useParams();
  const [vesselData, setVesselData] = useState();
  const { components, error, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.components
  );

  const fetchVesselData = async () => {
    try {
    const res = await api(vesselId);
    setVessesData(res);
    } catch (e) {
      // handle error
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchVesselData()
  });
```